# Custom status bar in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

As status bar style called, `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` is deprecated in iOS7 and up, what is the alternate for getting the similar status bar? How can we achieve this?

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIStatusBarStyle) {
    UIStatusBarStyleDefault                                     = 0, // Dark content, for use on light backgrounds
    UIStatusBarStyleLightContent     NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) = 1, // Light content, for use on dark backgrounds

    UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 1,
    UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque      NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 2,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From iOS7, all the statusBar is translucent, no statusbar is opaque,no way to do this if you only use statusBar. now we can configure navigationbar opaque to indirectly achieve it. `opaque navigationbar + UIStatusBarStyleDefault` is what you what.

Hope this help.